# ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript + Google Maps

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I'm having trouble getting my google map to work properly using geocoding and clientscript.registerstartupscript. I know my google javascript is fine (used on other pages), it's just not even hitting it.  I have this functionality working elsewhere in the website and can not figure out why it will not work!  Very frustrating!!  See my code below:

.aspx:

```
 <script>
 var geocoder;
 var map;
 function initialize() {
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
     var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 8,
         center: latlng,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
     codeAddress();
 }

 function codeAddress() {
     var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
     geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 map: map,
                 position: results[0].geometry.location
             });
         } else {
             alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
         }
     });
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

 <body onload="initialize()">
```

.aspx.cs:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script1",
       "codeAddress();");
```

The map must initialize, because it shows the empty google map shell, but it is not populating.

Firebug shows this at the bottom of the page:
`<script type="text/javascript">
    codeAddress();
    </script>`

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using below code.
Note : The values for the variables message & locationList is getting from codebehind, use a public variable and assign it in html.

```
<html>
<head id="Head1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var infowindow;
        var geocoder;
        var message = "<font style='font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;color:blue;'>206B Signal Hill Drive, <br/>Statesville,  NC 28625  USA</font>"; //<%= Message%>
        var locationList = "35.793286,-80.855383"; //<%= LocationList%>
        var args = locationList.split(",");

        function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(args[0], args[1]);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(args[0], args[1])
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map
            });
            marker.setTitle(message.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""));
            attachSecretMessage(marker, 0);

        }

        function attachSecretMessage(marker, number) {
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
        { content: message,
          size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
        });

        infowindow.open(map, marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
       }

  </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize();">
    <form method="post" id="Form1">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 763px; height: 340px;padding-top:100px;">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```